# How to copy (two-way sync) row to another sheet based on cell value in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that has a couple of sheets, the `Master` is the main one, and a couple of sheets like `Windows Servers`, `Linux Servers`, `Windows PCs`, and so on...

The `Master` sheet has a column called "**category**" which can be filled with these values:

- Windows Server
- Linux Server
- Windows PC
- etc...

My goal is to copy the entire row to the desired right sheet, so for example if a row in the `Master` sheet contains a category of "Windows Server", I want it to be copied the the `Windows Servers` sheet. and so on...

These are example screenshots I have found on the internet to somewhat clarify what I'm aiming to do:

[image]

[image]

I have used the "filter" function to accomplish this as such:

I have put this function in each sheet, this function in the `Windows Servers` sheet:
`=filter(Master!A:P,Master!C:C="Windows Server")`

[image]

[image]

[image]

This worked fine but not quite like what I wanted.
Yes, when I update the content of the row in the `Master` sheet it reflects on the other sheets, **but not the other way around, I want this to be bidirectional, in other words, "two-way sync".**

And It would be very useful for me if this can keep the same format of the cells as well when it does that.

Is there a way to make this happen?

Thank you all.

Comment: Wich columns you want to edit in both tabs"you reffered to them as sheets in your question"

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your comment here, but the thing is when I enter a new record (row) in the `Master` sheet and say for example it contained the category of  "Windows Server", all the content of this row should be copied to the `Windows Servers` sheet. so the distribution of the records (rows) in the `Master` sheet should be based on the cell value of the category. anything that is edited in the record (row) in the `Master` sheet should be reflected in the other sheet and vise vresa.